# Bash script to get mongoStats

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

Hoping someone has a bash script handy that will hit a mongodb and get the collection stats something like the below that I can use in a shell script?

```
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(), stats = [];
collectionNames.forEach(function (n) { stats.push(db[n].stats()); });
stats = stats.sort(function(a, b) { return b['size'] - a['size']; });
for (var c in stats) { print(stats[c]['ns'] + ": " + stats[c]['size'] + " (" + stats[c]['storageSize'] + ")"); }
```

UPDATE

one other question --- looking to prefix the line with a datestamp

```
"db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print('date +'%D %r %Z'''namespace=' + s['ns'] +',count=' + s['count']+',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']+',storageSize=' + s['storageSize']) })"
```

but my date code doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/index.html#scripting

Comment: Thanks! not sure how I missed that ---- looking at the command in the examples it says mongo test - I assume test in the dbname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mongo $DB_NAME --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print(s['ns'] + ',' + s['size'] + ',' + s['storageSize']) })" | sort --numeric-sort --reverse
```

It will print in a CSV format which you can you couple of tools to manipulate.

**Update**:

Just add `avgObjSize`, `totalIndexSize` and other keys you need, edit your main question with an output example so we can sort by whatever column you desire.

**Update 2:**

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); printjson({'namespace': s['ns'], 'size': s['size'], 'storage': s['storageSize']}) })

db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print('size=' + s['size'] +',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']) })
```

Comment: thanks! I'd really like to get the following: count, size, avg object size, and total index size

Comment: add avgObjSize & totalIndexSize, provide output example and the column you want to sort by and I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks - I was able to modify your example - this works for me... `--quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print(s['ns'] + ',' + s['size'] + ',' + s['count'] + s['avgObjSize'] + ',' + ',' + s['storageSize']) })"`

Comment: @Tony it looks quite the same :), what about the sorting ? did you pipe to sort -rn ? you can also sort by column with `--key` flag

Comment: going to ingest this data into splunk so no need to sort on the command... Is there a way to add some text before the variables? ie namespace=['ns'] ?

Comment: of course, you can also use printjson if you're using splunk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167187/discussion-between-tony-and-iddoe).